# In an excel range - ignore empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm concatenating using an excel range:

`Set rng = Range("A1:A8")`

If one of the cells withing the range is empty it adds a single space.

How do you stop this space from being added?

Comment: could you please post your whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have got constants in those non-empty cells:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A8").SpecialCells(2)
```

Unfortunately, non-contiguous ranges make that we can't put `rng` into an array or use it in a `Join` operation. You'll have to loop each cell in the range.

However, I would utilize `Application.Trim` instead of setting a range. This way we can work through memory (array) instead of a more sluggish `Range` object reference:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = [TRANSPOSE(A1:A8)]
Debug.Print Application.Trim(Join(arr, " "))

End Sub
```

Or, if you don't want to utilize `.Evaluate`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Range("A1:A8")
With Application
    Debug.Print .Trim(Join(.Transpose(.Index(arr, 0, 1)), " "))
End With

End Sub
```

<sub>***Note-1:*** We need `Transpose` to return a 1D-array to be able to use in `Join`.</sub>

<sub>***Note-2:*** If one has got access to `TEXTJOIN` function, there is no need for all this, but you can utilize that function in an array form.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are concatenating range then a simple loop may help:

```
Dim rng As range, cell As range

For Each cell In range("A1:A8") ' looking through the desired range
    If Not cell = "" Then ' if the cell is not empty we have to add it to range
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then ' if the range already has some cells in it
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell) ' we have to add the cell to an existing range
        Else ' if the range does not yet exists
            Set rng = cell ' create it and add the first cell
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is a very roundabout way of describing `SpecialCells` =)

Comment: Well, yes :) But anyway, it works, it is simple and one may always add any condition to filter needed cells.